# Gemalto Third Party dll Referencing in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, sdk, gemalto

I have a wpf application with a feature to read passports and driver's licenses using a gemalto QS1000 and the 3M SDK. The SDK and drivers are installed on my dev machine (C:\Program Files (x86)\3M\3M Page Reader\3.3.3.10\bin...). According to the documentation, during development I should change the debug working directory to that location. Everything works great!

Now comes deployment to production machine.

I have installed the same SDK and drivers on the production machine. According to the documentation, I should include all the appropriate dlls. What I don't understand is where I am to include these? Only a handful of the dlls are reference-able.

If I paste my app's output directory in the bin folder below, then it works just fine, but since I don't want to do that, I'm at a lost as to how to do this properly.

```
+ C:/
    + Program Files (x86)
        + 3M
            + 3M Page Reader
                + 3.3.3.10
                    + Bin (working directory on dev machine)
                        + MMMReaderDotNet40.dll (referenced in project)
                    + Config
                        + -- Needed files --
                    + Data
                        + -- Needed sub-directory --
                    + Documentation
                    + Drivers
                    + Logs
                        + -- Needed sub-directory --
                    + Plugins
                        + -- Needed sub-directory --
                    + SDK
                        + -- Code samples and such --
```

[Documentation part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AQCJ.png)

[Documentation part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMKQv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix, change the starting directory of the installed app's shortcut to be where i need it to be